# Email Status tracking

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I am looking for script in vba on MS outlook using which I can track the email response time and other details like type of email, status etc. I have some knowledge of Outlook VBA but not sure if it's possible using below steps:

1. On clicking the send button there should be userform where we have dropdown like type of email and status etc.
2. Send Button on userform which will orignally send email after verifing few condition like attachment, copy email to a person etc
3. Once I click send button on userform it should capture info of this email like sent to, subject, time also if its a reply email received from, received email subject and time and then transfer the info to excel file

Step 1 & 2 I am ok with Step 3 where I need help I know this can be done using tracking conversation but not sure how 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Appreciate any help in completing the development.

```
this is what i have writen so far 
ThisOutllokSession:

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal CurrentEmail As Object, Cancel As Boolean)    
UserForm1.Show
Cancel = True
MsgBox UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value & vbNewLine & UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value & vbNewLine & currentemail.to & vbNewLine & currentemail.Subject
Unload UserForm1
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\need help\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
here i want to get the from Email ID, email recieved time, Subject 
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
End Sub

Userform1 Coding
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Responce"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Question"
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Feedback"

Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "Pending"
Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "Complete"
Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "Follow Up"
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to show us what you've tried first before anyone can help you here... this is a bit too specific of a request for help. Maybe you should hire a programmer?

Comment: have added the coding where i reach right now if you can help in remaining part

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ItemSend` event to process message just before they are sent. You can display a user form and cancel the message submission (if necessary)

Comment: have added the coding where i reach right now if you can help in remaining part